# npm windows package.json wildcard select concat-cli

Tags: npm, package.json

I'm having some issues on Windows env. with npm & a package.json, mainly with one of the devDependencies, [concat-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-cli).
Here's a little sample of the package.json file:

```
...
scripts{
  ...  
  "js-vendor-concat": "concat-cli -f src/js/vendor/**/*.js -o dist/js/vendors.js",
  ...
}
....
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "concat-cli": "^4.0.0" 
  ...
}
```

So what happens is that every time I run that script in Windows env, I get `Error: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read at errorHandler (index.js:11:15)`. Thing is that on linux, this error doesn't come up.

Things tried so far:

- used `git-bash` and `cygwin` but same outcome
- changed the input path to: `src/js/vendor/*.js`, again same outcome

However if I specify the name of the file, it works, so I'm guessing its something related to that wildcard `*.js` selector?

Any tips or pointers are much appreciated, thanks!